# Can I define a morphism between complex numbers and $\mathbb{Q}_2$ using Gelfond's constant?

Tags: complex-numbers, p-adic-number-theory, group-isomorphism

> Can I define a  morphism between complex numbers and $\mathbb{Q}_2$ in this way using Gelfond's constant?

I'm exploring a (morphism? perhaps not the right word?) between the 2-adic and complex numbers using Gelfond's constant and trying to understand whether what I'm doing makes sense.

If we define Gelfond's constant to be $X=(-1)^{-i}$

Then we might say this is the multivalued function taking values $\{e^{-\pi},e^{\pi},e^{3\pi},e^{5\pi},\ldots\}$

So we might consider the natural log of this divided by $\pi$ to be the odd numbers:

$X=(-1)^{-i}=\{\ldots e^{-\pi},e^{\pi},e^{3\pi},e^{5\pi},\ldots\}$

$$\frac{\ln(X)}{\pi}=2\mathbb{Z}-1$$

I *think* I'm on fairly solid ground so far - am I not?

Am I right to call this $\mathbb{N}_2^{\times}$?

It would seem $\displaystyle2\mathbb{Z}=\frac{\ln(X\cdot e^{\pi})}{\pi}=\frac{\ln(X)}{\pi}+1$

So I can define $\displaystyle\mathbb{Z}=\frac{\ln(X)}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}$

How might I now define the sets

A: $\langle2\rangle=\{\ldots1/2,1,2,4,8,\ldots\}$

B: $\mathbb{Z}_2$

C: $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$

in a comparable way? And

D: the metric $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2$

E: the valuation $v_2(x)$

For C it would seem I can say $$\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}\cap\mathbb{Q}=\ln\left(\frac{X^{\tfrac{\pi}{\ln(X)}}}{\pi}\right)$$ since this gives us the set of ratios of any two odd numbers.

For A, the best I can do is: $\langle2\rangle=2^{\mathbb{Z}}=\sqrt{2}X^{\tfrac{\ln{2}}{2\pi}}$

which again is a bit convoluted.

As for the metric; perhaps this doesn't have a place here if I'm only working with sets of numbers.  Or maybe it can be a multi-valued metric.  Not really sure where to start with that.

As a little background, the motivation behind this is to understand the orthogonality of the orbits of a certain two functions in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and I'm investigating whether such a morphism will give me some extra tools like regular calculus and complex number algebra; with which I'm a little more familiar than p-adic calculus.

Comment: Morphism of ... what? Fields? There is (assuming axiom of choice) a homomorphism of fields from $\Bbb{Q}_2$ to $\Bbb{C}$, but I can't describe one. BTW $\Bbb{Z}_2$ contains numbers other than ratios of odd integers. For example, to any integer $n\equiv1\pmod8$ there exists an element $u\in\Bbb{Z}_2^*$ such that $u^2=n$. In other words, for example $\sqrt{-7}\in\Bbb{Z}_2^*$. Also $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is an uncountable set, so it necessarily also contains elements that are transcendental over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: I only actually need a morphism which preserves the image of $\mathbb{Z}_2\cap\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ but any superset thereof will be a starting point.

Comment: I think I'm attempting to define the morphism $f:\mathbb{something}\to\mathbb{C}$ where $f(x)=e^{(x+2k)\pi}$ but not sure just yet what "something" is.